# F# TryGetValue, can't access the value?

Tags: f#

I am using TryGetValue on a Dictionary in F# and it returns an object `bool * Dictionary<int, object>`

I have been googling for hours but how do I access the bool component of this object so I can check if it has returned a value?

Please save me from going postal...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are a few options.

The simplest is probably:

```
let found, value = dict.TryGetValue key
```

Alternatively:

```
let pair = dict.TryGetValue key
let found = fst pair
let value = snd pair
```

The most common pattern is this:

```
match dict.TryGetValue key with
  | true, value -> (* do something with value *)
  | _           -> (* handle the case of value not found *)
```

Comment: The intellisense and the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.8) shows only the method overload with 2 parameters: __key__ and __ref value__ .  How/Where can I find the single parameter method signature ? (If I use the sugegsted overload with one parameter it works anymay)

Comment: @Alex75 I don't know for sure, but I believe this is special handing in the F# compiler for functions that return a bool and have an out parameter.